# How do you set the accesskey for a ToggleSwitch?

Tags: javascript, windows-8

I'm working on a Windows 8 app using HTML/JS. We have a WinJS.UI.ToggleSwitch element and want to set the accesskey property on it for keyboard navigation.

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ToggleSwitch"></div>
```

It looks like that ends up in a nested div structure with multiple elements. Using DOM explorer, the actual control looks like this:

```
<input class="win-switch" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="ms__id77" type="range" max="1" step="1"></input>
```

I'm able to add an accesskey property to this div in DOM explorer and it works. My question is how can I add it to the control in the original markup?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the implementation of this control, it's going to be hard. I see you have two options:

1. In the code that constructs this control, do the "unpleasant" thing, and querySelector for the element, and set it yourself.
2. Derive from WinJS.UI.ToggleSwitch, and monkey patch _setElement, to allow you to do it yourself after the fact.

Both of these are highly subject to changes in future versions, with 2 being the most likely to break since you are monkey patching in an internal method.